# Unable to attach files in Odoo when using HTTPS via nginx

Tags: ssl, nginx, odoo, odoo-9

Been having an issue and finally narrowed it down, but can't find a solution.

If I setup nginx to redirect to HTTPS, everything works great, SSL connection and all, except when writing messages in Odoo, our staff can't attach files. It gets stuck on "uploading" (blue bar over the file icon). There's no useful output in the log, even on the most verbose debug level.

As a workaround, I've disabled SSL, but I'd like to turn it back on. Suggestions? Running Odoo v9.0c.

Comment: What's the configuration of the SSL enabled server?

Comment: Here's /etc/nginx/sites-available/default:
https://pastebin.com/bJsTHKDh

Basically followed this guide: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-secure-nginx-with-let-s-encrypt-on-ubuntu-16-04

Comment: What request is being sent and how does the server respond?

Comment: I'm not quite sure. Even the most verbose log just shows this when uploading a file (SSL is currently off, but with it on it's also a 200):

`2017-08-15 12:51:22,905 14856 INFO xxx-server werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - - [15/Aug/2017 12:51:22] "POST /web/binary/upload_attachment HTTP/1.0" 200 -`